# Artifactory not listing all repositories in settings generation

Tags: maven, repository, artifactory

I have set up a local Artifactory installation.
Apart from the pre-existing repos, I have created a few additional ones.

However, when trying to generate `settings.xml` file, the drop down menus do not incorporate all existing repos.

Here is the list of existing repos:

[image]

And here are the only options available for say `Releases` (same goes for all other options, e.g. `Snapshots`, etc)

[image]

Why aren't other repos visible to these drop down menus?

**UPDATE**: I see now that when exporting maven settings, only **virtual** or **remote** repositories can be used. Why are local repositories excluded from this process?

(but are eligible as deploy targets in `<distributionManagement>` elements?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating the Settings.xml file in Artifactory, Artifactory will only show the virtual repositories available. 
This considered as the best practice, as this will allow the Artifactory Admins to change, in case needed, the used repositories in the background and the end user will need to change nothing on his end. 
By default, Artifactory has 'libs-releases' virtual, for resolution of RELEASE artifacts and 'libs-snapshots' for resolution of SNAPSHOTS artifacts.
You can read more on virtual repositories in the link below:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories